# Array Filter - Looking for string value with letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I have a strange problem where my array filter works on all values within an array, except when the string value contains a mixture of numbers and letters. At least that's what I think is the issue.

Please see the two examples below.  In the first case I am looking for records where `card_id` has a value `cardid-1602670475144`.  In this case the filter array is always empty.

```js
let arr = [{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c450b"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670475144","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"100"},"career_stage":"Veteran","forTrade":"Yes","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"16"},"player":"Trent Williams","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"25"},"purchase_date":"Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Patch","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Holo Silver"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c4537"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670491958","brand":"Playbook","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"85"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"80"},"player":"Ryan Kerrigan","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"299"},"purchase_date":"Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Signatures","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Base","year":"2011"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f3032d764f7ad4c455f"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670496512","brand":"Contenders","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"144"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"Yes","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"0"},"player":"Jawan Jamison","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"21"},"purchase_date":"Mon Sep 14 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Ticket Autographs","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Cracked Ice","year":"2013"}]

 function filterCards(cardsArray, path, cardProperty) {
  console.log("ORIGINAL ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(cardsArray));
  if (path === "want" || "own") {
    path = path[0].toUpperCase() + path.substring(1);
  }
  var filtered = Object.values(cardsArray).filter(function (card) {
    if (card[cardProperty] === path) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  console.log("FILTERED ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(filtered));
  return filtered;
}

var newArray = filterCards(
        arr,
       "cardid-1602670475144",
       "card_id", 
        
      );
```

In the second case I modify the data so that `card_id` has a value `1602670475144` (i.e. I have removed the `cardid-` prefix) and look for that. Then the correct data is returned.

```js
let arr = [{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c450b"},"card_id":"1602670475144","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"100"},"career_stage":"Veteran","forTrade":"Yes","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"16"},"player":"Trent Williams","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"25"},"purchase_date":"Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Century Materials","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Patch","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Holo Silver"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c4537"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670491958","brand":"Playbook","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"85"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"80"},"player":"Ryan Kerrigan","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"299"},"purchase_date":"Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Signatures","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Base","year":"2011"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b5f3032d764f7ad4c455f"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670496512","brand":"Contenders","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"144"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"Yes","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"0"},"player":"Jawan Jamison","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"21"},"purchase_date":"Mon Sep 14 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Ticket Autographs","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Cracked Ice","year":"2013"}]

 function filterCards(cardsArray, path, cardProperty) {
  console.log("ORIGINAL ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(cardsArray));
  if (path === "want" || "own") {
    path = path[0].toUpperCase() + path.substring(1);
  }
  var filtered = Object.values(cardsArray).filter(function (card) {
    if (card[cardProperty] === path) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  console.log("FILTERED ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(filtered));
  return filtered;
}

var newArray = filterCards(
        arr,
       "1602670475144",
       "card_id"
        
      );
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here; I feel like I must be making some stupid mistake!

Comment: You don't have to use `Object.values(cardsArray).filter()`--instead use `cardsArray.filter()`

Comment: I believe you want to do `if (path === "want" || path === "own")` This modified your `path` property you were looking for in card objects

Comment: Yes, `path === "want" || "own"` will **always** be true since "own" (like all non-empty strings) is truthy in JavaScript.

Comment: wow, I didn't know that!  `own` and `want` are paths in urls so I'll have to look at that.  You're right that taking the condition out to check for them makes the code work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function filterCards(cardsArray, path, cardProperty) {
  console.log("ORIGINAL ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(cardsArray));
  if (path === "want" || path === "own") {
    path = path[0].toUpperCase() + path.substring(1);
  }
  var filtered = cardsArray.filter(card =>  card[cardProperty] === path);
  console.log("FILTERED ARRAY " + JSON.stringify(filtered));
  return filtered;
}

let arr = [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c450b"
  },
  "card_id": "1602670475144",
  "brand": "National Treasures",
  "card_number": {
    "$numberDouble": "100"
  },
  "career_stage": "Veteran",
  "forTrade": "Yes",
  "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
  "manufacturer": "Panini",
  "number": {
    "$numberDouble": "16"
  },
  "player": "Trent Williams",
  "print_run": {
    "$numberDouble": "25"
  },
  "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
  "series": "Century Materials",
  "status": "Own",
  "team": "Washington Football Team",
  "type": "Patch",
  "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
  "variation": "Holo Silver"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8b5f2f32d764f7ad4c4537"
  },
  "card_id": "cardid-1602670491958",
  "brand": "Playbook",
  "card_number": {
    "$numberDouble": "85"
  },
  "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
  "forTrade": "",
  "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
  "manufacturer": "Panini",
  "number": {
    "$numberDouble": "80"
  },
  "player": "Ryan Kerrigan",
  "print_run": {
    "$numberDouble": "299"
  },
  "purchase_date": "Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
  "series": "Rookie Signatures",
  "status": "Own",
  "team": "Washington Football Team",
  "type": "Auto",
  "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
  "variation": "Base",
  "year": "2011"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f8b5f3032d764f7ad4c455f"
  },
  "card_id": "cardid-1602670496512",
  "brand": "Contenders",
  "card_number": {
    "$numberDouble": "144"
  },
  "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
  "forTrade": "Yes",
  "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
  "manufacturer": "Panini",
  "number": {
    "$numberDouble": "0"
  },
  "player": "Jawan Jamison",
  "print_run": {
    "$numberDouble": "21"
  },
  "purchase_date": "Mon Sep 14 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
  "series": "Rookie Ticket Autographs",
  "status": "Own",
  "team": "Washington Football Team",
  "type": "Auto",
  "user": "jinky32@gmail.com",
  "variation": "Cracked Ice",
  "year": "2013"
}]

var newArray = filterCards(
  arr,
  "1602670475144",
  "card_id"
);
```

The issue is you're searching for the number exactly. When cardid- is in front, it won't find anything because nothing matches **exactly**. I recommend you search for cardid-1602670475144 instead of 1602670475144. This matches correctly.

(I updated the code snippet to be more concise and use ES6--I recommend you use it if possible)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Swapping in `card[cardProperty].includes(path)` flags a syntax warning in  VSCode for me

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: If you just remove the `card[cardProperty].includes(path)` part from your answer I can mark it as the answer.  The fix is actually the change you make in the if statement ` if (path === "want" || path === "own")` from `if (path === "want" || "own")` it seems.  Do you know why that makes a difference?

Comment: It's because when that statement runs, it modifies the path. That statement **always** runs because "own" is a separate statement. When the program is run, it thinks you're trying to check if "own" is `true`. In JavaScript, non-empty strings are `true`. So, that statement always runs. It runs when it should be modifying it as I did above.